AWS Flink Memory Gradually Increasing
I have a Java app running on AWS Flink version 1.15.
The app aggregates numbers in a keyed stream over 1-minute windows.
Data is received from Kinesis input stream and sent over to Kinesis output stream.
Checkpoints are successfully created every 15 minutes, parallelism = 128, parallelism_per_kpu = 8.
For some reason, the AWS Flink dashboard shows a gradual increase in heap memory consumption over a period of days, and I'm not sure if it's normal or not (CPU on the other hand remains low and stable). This is the code:
import com.app.product.javacommons.dto.UpdateDto;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.StateTtlConfig;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ValueState;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ValueStateDescriptor;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.time.Time;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.ProcessWindowFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;

public class UpdateProcessWindowFunction
    extends ProcessWindowFunction<UpdateDto, UpdateDto, String, TimeWindow> {

static final long KEY_TTL_IN_MINUTES = 5;

static final int INCREMENTAL_CLEANUP_BATCH_SIZE = 10000;

static final boolean RUN_CLEANUP_FOR_EVERY_RECORD = true;

static final String VALUE_STATE_DESCRIPTOR_NAME = "updateState";

private final StateTtlConfig ttlConfig = StateTtlConfig.newBuilder(Time.minutes(KEY_TTL_IN_MINUTES))
        .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
        .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired)
        .cleanupIncrementally(INCREMENTAL_CLEANUP_BATCH_SIZE, RUN_CLEANUP_FOR_EVERY_RECORD)
        .build();

private transient ValueState<UpdateDto> state;

@Override
public void process(
        String key, Context context, Iterable<UpdateDto> elements, Collector<UpdateDto> out)
        throws Exception {

    // Initialize the state with TTL
    if (state == null) {
        ValueStateDescriptor<UpdateDto> descriptor =
                new ValueStateDescriptor<>(VALUE_STATE_DESCRIPTOR_NAME, UpdateDto.class);
        descriptor.enableTimeToLive(ttlConfig);
        state = context.globalState().getState(descriptor);
    }

    // Get the current state
    UpdateDto accumulator = state.value();

    // Initialize accumulator
    if (accumulator == null) {
        accumulator = new UpdateDto();
    }

    int totalCount = 0;

    // Process incoming records
    for (UpdateDto element : elements) {
        totalCount += element.getCount();

        accumulator.setExpiryTime(element.getExpiryTime());
        accumulator.setWithLastOccurrence(element.isWithLastOccurrence());
        accumulator.setSource(element.getSource());
        accumulator.setTarget(element.getTarget());
        accumulator.setFieldName(element.getFieldName());
    }

    // Update accumulator count
    accumulator.setCount(totalCount);

    // Update the state
    state.update(accumulator);

    // Emit the accumulated result
    out.collect(accumulator);
}
}

Memory increase:


What state backend are you using? As per https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/state/StateTtlConfig.Builder.html#cleanupIncrementally-int-boolean-,

Note: At the moment incremental cleanup is implemented only for Heap state backend. Setting it for RocksDB will have no effect.

